# How to set value for elements on an excel range

Tags: excel, vba, syntax

I am trying to write a function in VBA to use in several parts of an excel file. The function should receive a selected range and multiply every element on the range by 1.13 and then return a ranage with the new totals.

I have made tests for the function receiving and returning a range, I have succesfully pulled the value I want from the range applied the multplication and set the result on an variable. But I seem to not be able to set the value of an element in the range ( I have even tried declaring a temp range inside the function, but to no avail) I'm pretty sure this should be vary easy and I am just not getting it.

```
Public Function STax(Range1 As Range) As Range
    Dim Index
    For Index = 1 To Range1.Count
    Range1(Index).Value = Range1(Index).Value * 1.13
    Next Index
    STax = Range1

End Function
```

I want to have a function called STax where I can call con the excel file =STax(A1:A15) and it will just give me each value times 1.13. Ex

| Range | STax |
| --- | --- |
| 14.15 | 15.99 |
| 13.26 | 14.98 |
| 35.39 | 39.99 |
| 22.11 | 24.98 |

From that result work out other calculations I need to make, but I am stuck on this step to move forward. Any assitance will be greatly appreciated

Comment: User-defined functions called from a cell are limited and can generally only return values, not modify other cells. Your function should be returning value(s), not a `Range`. For the same reason, `Range1(Index).Value = Range1(Index).Value * 1.13` won't work as you intended. See [limitations of custom functions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel-f2f0ce5d-8ea5-6ce7-fddc-79d36192b7a1).

Comment: Ohhhh I imagined I was missing something like that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return an array of modified values:

```
Public Function STax(Range1 As Range) As Variant
    Dim arr, i As Long
    arr = Range1.Value                  'read input range to array
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)         'loop array
        arr(i, 1) = arr(i, 1) * 1.13    'modify values
    Next i
    STax = arr                          'return array
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much Tim! I had thought that maybe I needed to work something out with arrays, but I had not understood that  range1.value was giving me an array to work with